# Return a bundling file in Web Api MVC

Tags: api, optimization, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.0

I wanted my API could return a Bundling files.

I have this bundle on app_start:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));
```

and return this bundle on the controller:

```
return File(("~/Content/css"), "text/css");
```

but I have an error message says "Could not find file".
how could the client get the bundling css from my API?
I wanted something like a google CDN providing a bundle script.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a controller action returning the bundle you could directly have the client request the bundle. For example for styles:

```
Scripts.Url("~/Content/css")
```

would give you the url of the bundle to reference.

Comment: no, I wanted my client request through the URL. so it would be something like api.com/get/css